# class index differ error in weka

Tags: nlp, weka

I want to do text classification with weka. I have a train and a test file (Persian language). first I load the train file and then choose "string to word vector" in preprocess. And because of choosing that, the class position goes to the start. For moving the class to its index (which is 2 in the files), I can go either to "Edit" part and right click on the class column and choose "attribute as class" or just in classify menu, choose (NOM)class. (unless most of the algorithms would be inactive). I run SMO and save the model. The problem is, after opening the test file, and click on "re-evaluate the model on current test set", this error occurs that, "...class index differ: 1!=2". I know it is because after opening the test file, again the class column goes to the start. For train part I solved the problem as I described above. But how can I solve it for the test part, too?

sample train file:
[image]

sample test file:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I changed the files to vector based on 1000 most frequent words in train file and made a numeric arff file for the train and test file, then for both of them in the "classify" menu in "Test options" I chose "(Nom) class.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the same transformation(s) on your testset before you use it to evaluate a trained model. When using the GUI, you could use the preprocessor view from the explorer, apply the same transformations by hand and than save the set to a new arff file. When you want to conduct a series of experiment, I suggest writing a routine that does your transformation for you.

That would look a little something like this:

```
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ArffSaver;
import weka.core.converters.CSVLoader;
import weka.filters.Filter;
import weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove;
import weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Reorder;
import weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.NumericToNominal;

import java.io.File;

public class DataConverter
{
 public static void Convert(String sourcepath,String destpath) throws Exception
 {
 CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader();
 loader.setSource(new File(sourcepath));
 Instances data = loader.getDataSet();

 Remove remove = new Remove();                         
 remove.setOptions(weka.core.Utils.splitOptions("-R 1")); 
 remove.setInputFormat(data);                          
 data = Filter.useFilter(data, remove);   

 Reorder reorder = new Reorder();
 reorder.setOptions(weka.core.Utils.splitOptions("-R first-29,31-last,30"));
 reorder.setInputFormat(data);                          
 data = Filter.useFilter(data, reorder);   

 NumericToNominal ntn = new NumericToNominal();
 ntn.setOptions(weka.core.Utils.splitOptions("-R first,last"));
 ntn.setInputFormat(data);                          
 data = Filter.useFilter(data, ntn); 

 // save ARFF
 ArffSaver saver = new ArffSaver();
 saver.setInstances(data);
 saver.setFile(new File(destpath));
 //saver.setDestination(new File(destpath));
 saver.writeBatch();
 }
 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
 {
   File folder = new File("..\\..\\data\\output\\learning\\csv\\");
   File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

   for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
     String target = listOfFiles[i].getName();
     target = target.substring(0, target.lastIndexOf("."));
     System.out.println("converting file " + (i + 1) + "/" + listOfFiles.length);
     Convert("..\\..\\data\\output\\learning\\csv\\" + listOfFiles[i].getName(), "..\\..\\data\\output\\learning\\arff\\" + target + ".arff");
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Also: The reorder filter can help you place your target class at the end of the file. It takes a new order of the old indices as arguments. In this case you could apply `Reorder -R 2-last,1`

Comment: @S van Balen, I don't know java. Is there any way I solve this problem in weka itself rather than writing any code? thanks

Comment: Absolutely! Basically you just execute the stringToWordVector filter from the GUI, save the result to testset.arff (or whatever), and then execute that same exercise for your training set. You can then load your train set in the GUI, and configure any classifier to use the saved test set for evaluation.